# Object generator function not doing what it should and returning no result.

Tags: javascript, node.js, yield

Im trying to learn how to use object generators and use the yield command to do some synchronous operations in my nodejs controller.

I want this to first execute the FOO call, and THEN when returned, execute the BAR call.

In this case I was expecting the console to show

```
Hello FOO
Hello BAR
```

But all I get is

```
Result [object Generator]
Result [object Generator]
```

I dont even get the console.logs inside the function.

```
  var myResult = findUser1("FOO")
  console.log("Result " + myResult )

  myResult = findUser1("BAR")
  console.log("Result " + myResult )

function* findUser1(UID) {
    var user1 = yield setTimeout("Hello " + UID, 2000);
    console.log("This should be shown AFTER user1 has a result");
    console.log(user1);
    return user1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), not generator functions. Generator functions return *IterableIterator* objects. These objects adhere to the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol), meaning they have a `next()` method that returns an object with a `value` field and a `done` boolean field. They also adhere to the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol), meaning they have a special `@@iterator` method that returns an iterator object (in this case, it returns itself since it is its own iterator).

Promises, on the other hand, represent a value that does not exist yet but may exist at some time in the future. ES6 also gives us [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) which simplify using promises with an `await` keyword. Here's how your code might look using async functions:

```
async function findUser(id) {
  const user = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Hello " + id), 2000);
  });
  console.log("This should be shown AFTER user has a result");
  console.log(user);
  return user;
}

async function getUsers() {
  const user1 = await findUser("FOO");
  console.log("Result " + user1);
  const user2 = await findUser("BAR");
  console.log("Result " + user2);
}

getUsers();
```

If you don't want to use `async`/`await` syntax, the following is equivalent:

```
function findUser(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Hello " + id), 2000);
  }).then((user) => {
    console.log("This should be shown AFTER user has a result");
    console.log(user);
    return user;
  });
}

findUser("FOO")
  .then(user1 => console.log("Result " + user1))
  .then(() => findUser("BAR"))
  .then(user2 => console.log("Result " + user2));
```

Comment: Waou!!! I didnt even know there was a `async function` thingy - I will try your example at once!!

Comment: I get a strange error:  `async function findUser(id) {` and `SyntaxError: Unexpected token function` can you help?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard What version of Node are you using? Both versions of this code work if you copy and paste them into the latest version of Chrome's console, and modern versions of Node support async functions (and even async generator functions)

Comment: @torbenrudgaard You need to use at least Node 7.6, or transpile the code using babel and [`babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/). But if you can upgrade to Node 7 or 8, I would highly recommend it, as you get native support for more ES6 features!

Comment: ARGH!  `v6.11.0 LTS
Recommended For Most Users`  I guess thats what happens when you follow guides hehehe...  Let me update to version 8.1.2

Comment: sbking it works perfectly!!  And it does EXACTLY what I want it to do.  Can I ask, why do you need `const user = await....` is there a particular reason why you use const in these cases?

Comment: I been playing and made `var user = await myStuff();` in this case myStuff is just a normal `var myStuff = function() {do stuff}` but I keep getting an error that "myStufff is not a function, and ` Unhandled promise rejection` - does this mean that await will ONLY work with promises, and not with functions?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard Read up on `let` and `const` - they are block scoped variable declarations and I would recommend using them instead of `var` whenever possible. I use `const` because it signifies that I won't reassign a new value to that variable name. Note that const values are not immutable - you can still change object properties, push values onto arrays, etc. So `const foo = {a: 1}; foo = {a: 2};` is invalid, but `const foo = {a: 1}; foo.a = 2;` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Ihh sbking, last question.  I tried calling `const user1 = await findUser("WOO");` directly from the main function without being inside an `async function` but got `Unexpected identifier` - it seem await will ONLY work if inside async function correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146908/discussion-between-sbking-and-torbenrudgaard).

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you must check some generator tutorials. for using generators you must first create generator then use it so your code become like this:

```
var findUser = findUser("FOO");
var myResult = findUser.next().value;
console.log("Result " + myResult );
findUser.next();


function* findUser1(UID) {
    var user1 = yield setTimeout(() => {"Hello " + UID}, 2000);
    console.log("This should be shown AFTER user1 has a result");
    console.log(user1);
    return user1;
}
```

please note that you must pass callback function as a first argument of `setTimeout` function, and your return value of next function is a object with form:

```
{
  value: ...,
  done: false
}
```

and in your application is a object returned from timeout function, in order to complete your function you must call `next()` again.
please note that `yield` command in your generator returned to you what is passed into `next()`.

At the end let's review some methods on create control flow with generators:

```
function asyncFlow(generatorFunction) {
  function callback(err) {
    if (err) {
      return generator.throw(err);
    }
    const results = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    generator.next(results.length > 1 ? results : results[0]);
  }
  const generator = generatorFunction(callback);
  generator.next();
}

asyncFlow(function* (callback) {
  console.log('1. Hello');
  yield setTimeout(callback, 2000);
  console.log('2. 2000ms');
  yield setTimeout(callback, 1000);
  console.log('3. 1000ms');
});
```

`co` is a good library for generator-based control flow, you can find its detail [here](https://github.com/tj/co).

Beside generators you can use native js or `async` feature of ECMA2017 for manage your control flow.

Comment: Hi Parham, thanks for the answer. I actually tried several tutorials but many of them do not work as they describe while others are really hard to understand.  So you must first create the generator, I will try that now.

Comment: I will try to add more detail in my answer to help you more, you want to create synchronous like function in nodejs with generators ?

Comment: What I need to do is find one user, if he exists do some stuff and then find the other user etc..  I tried with promises but it gets too messy (call back hell) - so I decided to try and learn generators. I just tried your example and get 3 lines:  `Result [object Object]` and `
This should be shown AFTER user1 has a result` and ´undefined`

Comment: @torbenrudgaard Did you see my answer with `async`/`await` syntax? Promises with no callback hell!